# Why is PHP producing high load on apache when it reads a file over the network?

Tags: php, apache, load

When I read from a file (independently while using fopen or file_get_contents) on a URL and the file is not answering fast, PHP produces a relatively high load on its apache process when
waiting for the URL to respond.

If I have some more visitors on my website and they all run the same script, the apache (and even the server) is going to die because there are these apache processes with the high load
which will not end in a normal time.

Are there any solutions how to handle this problem or how to reduce the load of these apache processes still waiting for the URL to respond?

Comment: This is called "the bottleneck" then.

Comment: Try using curl, which uses a different infrastructure than fopen/file_get_contents. Those might be using a tight polling loop, producing the high cpu usage you're seeing.

Comment: The problem is, that I need to use fopen because of a the crappy infrastructure on the other side.
So there is no way to reduce the load?

Comment: Would you happen to have found any solution, ever?

Comment: @user1111929 : Unfortunatley no. You could try to switch to PHP-FPM, but I do not know, whether this helps.